# -bash: [: missing `]' error

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to run this for loop but I'm getting the same error message: -bash: [: missing `]'

```
for FILE in *.fasta
do
  a=$(grep -c ">" $FILE)
  if [ "$a" == 15] 
  then
    mv $FILE folder/
  fi
done
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this for you automatically.

Comment: ...and btw, you've got more bugs than just the one discussed in the linked code -- really *do* run your code through shellcheck. And in the future, use the `{}` button in the SO editor or four-space indents to format code.

Comment: (the linked question has a different error because they left out the space on the left-hand `[` as well as the right-hand `]`, but the fix is exactly the same. And btw, `==` actually isn't valid in POSIX sh -- it's a ksh/bash extension to allow it, but if you want to write compatible code, get used to using `=` for string comparisons in shell instead).

Comment: (also, all-upper-case names are used with variables meaningful to the operating system or shell; to avoid conflicts, use lowercase names for your own variables. See the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, specifying lower-case names to be reserved for application use -- while that spec is on environment variables, it applies to regular shell variables as well, since writing to a shell variable will automatically overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: (...and quotes are *important*. A file named `-i hello.fasta`, for instance, would pass the `-i` argument to `mv`, unless you fix your code to put double-quotes around the expansion for its name).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just beginning to learn coding. I didn't know about shellcheck! very usefull